# Stop Script Execution after set time

Tags: php

I use an external source to get the location of users to my website so that i can customize the site for there location however the external source i am using can sometimes be very slow and as such slows my site down i get the external data using `cURL` and i have implemented a timeout function `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1000);` but once the timeout has kicked in the page stops loading and half the page is missing.

This is the script is use on my website

```
$i = 1;
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
if(empty($_SESSION['country'])) { 
  $conchk = $geoplugin->countryName;
  $_SESSION['country'] =  $conchk;
}
else { $conchk = $_SESSION['country']; }
if(empty($conchk)) {$countrygeo = "NULL_CONT";} else {$countrygeo = $conchk;}
//$countrygeo = "Spain";
$country_find = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country_list 
  WHERE country='$countrygeo' LIMIT 1");
while($row_cou = mysql_fetch_array($country_find)) {
  $rowcov = $row_cou[1];
  //Geo-location default!
  print "<option selected value=\"$rowcov\">$rowcov</option>\n";
  $kvar = 1;
}
//finish first while loop!
//if we cant find the geo-country in the list print the whole table!
$country_full_list_print = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country_list 
  ORDER BY country ASC");
while($row_full = mysql_fetch_array($country_full_list_print)) {
  if( ($row_full[1] == "United Kingdom") && ($i == 1) && (empty($kvar)) ) { 
    print "<option selected value=\"$row_full[1]\">$row_full[1]</option>\n"; $i++; }   
    //always print uk as default if no results.
elseif ($row_full[1] == $rowcov) {  }
else { 
  print "<option value=\"$row_full[1]\">$row_full[1]</option>\n"; } //this is the default print!
} //close while loop and if num_rows less than 1.
```

If anyone has any ideas how to stop the $geoplugin but continue loading the page it would be much appreciated.

Comment: try an Exceptions loop. http://nz.php.net/exceptions

Comment: @Dagon: hehe, php.net discloses your location without need of visiting the profile :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only good solution to this involves Javascript: move the part where you call into the external resource to another script and invoke it with AJAX as soon as practical. This way you can impose a strict time limit on that separate script, and if you overstep it there's no issue: the AJAX request will fail but you can handle that gracefully and it won't affect the rest of your page.

You should be doing this already, as even if the slow external response doesn't leave your page half-baked it still makes *your* page look responsible for any delay.